# drupal user badges not able to display image.

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have installed and enabled user badge module .Created user badge and assigned it to certain users . 
However I m not able to view the image. When i click on user , select badge I can see the text associated with it but not the actual image.

What could be the problem here. IS there any way I can get the documentation for the module?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of User Badges are you using? I think the problem should be solved now as the User Badges module has a production version out and most of the bugs have been taken care of. So, please upgrade to the latest 7.x-1.0 recommended release.

We were not able to add a badge in the Rules action because I think, The Drupal-7 version of User Badges was not integrated with Rules. Should do comment but can't

Comment: I m using the current  User badges 7.x-3.2 Problem is I can able to view the image and badge name in badge configuration settings but when i navigate to user profile . Under badges i don't see the image . Even under badge tab i see only badge text and not the image. I tried every type of images still no effect .